# Pass different parameter to each screen when I use TabNavigator (react-navigation)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm making app with using React Native and react-navigation.

I'm looking for a way to pass different parameter to each screen. Each screen is same class. 
There should be a way to archive it but I couldn't find so far,

except declaring two different wrapper class each and pass screenProps, but it seems insane.

```
const Tab = TabNavigator(
{
    main:{screen:TodoList}, //pass "abc" for this screen
    main2:{screen:TodoList} //pass "def" for this screen
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the other signature if you have custom props :

```
const Tab = TabNavigator(
{
    main:{ screen: (props) => <TodoList {...props } myProp="abc" />}, //pass "abc" for this screen
    main2:{ screen: (props) => <TodoList {...props } myProp="def" />} //pass "def" for this screen
}
```

If you have shared "prop" common among all screens, you can pass it via `screenProps` when initiating the `Tab` itslef.

```
<Tab screenProps={{myCommonProp: "ghijkl"}} />
```

Comment: Welcome my friend!

Comment: Could you answer my question please?

Comment: I don't have any perspective of your project how is it structured, that's why It is hard to recommend in this situation. I really want to help as possible as I can. 

Comment: Yes, you're right. And everything works well! your code does not need to be modified. I did mistake. Thanks again!

Comment: Could you look this question too please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47794833/nested-drawer-stacknavigator-firing-draweropen-is-not-working-on-react-native