# Nested Drawer-StackNavigator, firing "DrawerOpen" is not working on React-Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm making app with using React Native with react-navigation.

[My App's hierarchy]

*Drawer(App)

ㄴ StackNavigator

ㄴ StackNavigator

What I want to is fire `navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen');`

I can show my Drawer by dragging from left edge but it's not triggered by pressing "Menu button" on the left of Navigation header. I've spent so many times to archive this. Please help me.

```
const Nav = StackNavigator({
    mainnav_list:{
        screen: (props) => <TodoList {...props} dbCollectionName={props.screenProps.dbCollectionName}/>,
        navigationOptions:({navigation}) => ({
            headerLeft:(
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {console.log(navigation); navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen');}}>
                    <Text style={{color:'white', marginLeft:15}}>Menu</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            )
        })
    },
    mainnav_detail:{screen: TodoDetail}
}
,
{
    navigationOptions:(props) => ({
        title:props.screenProps.dbCollectionName,
        headerBackTitle:null,
        headerStyle:{backgroundColor:'#000'},
        headerTitleStyle:{color:'#fff'},
        headerTintColor:'#fff',
    })
})

const AppDrawer = DrawerNavigator(
{
    drawer1:{screen:() => <Nav screenProps={{dbCollectionName:'todos'}}/> },
    drawer2:{screen:() => <Nav screenProps={{dbCollectionName:'todos2'}}/> }
})

AppRegistry.registerComponent('TodosFS', () => AppDrawer);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it!!

```
const Nav = StackNavigator({
    mainnav_list:{
        screen: (props) => <TodoList {...props} dbCollectionName={props.screenProps.dbCollectionName}/>,
        navigationOptions:(props) => ({
            headerLeft:(
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {props.screenProps.drawerNavigation.navigate('DrawerOpen');}}>
                    <Text style={{color:'white', marginLeft:15, fontWeight:'bold'}}>Menu</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            )
        })
    },
    mainnav_detail:{screen: TodoDetail}
}
,
{
    navigationOptions:(props) => ({
        title:props.screenProps.dbCollectionName,
        headerBackTitle:null,
        headerStyle:{backgroundColor:'#000'},
        headerTitleStyle:{color:'#fff'},
        headerTintColor:'#fff',
    })
})

const AppDrawer = DrawerNavigator(
{
    drawer1:{screen:({navigation}) => <Nav screenProps={{dbCollectionName:'todos', drawerNavigation:navigation}}/> },
    drawer2:{screen:({navigation}) => <Nav screenProps={{dbCollectionName:'todos2', drawerNavigation:navigation}}/> }
})

AppRegistry.registerComponent('TodosFS', () => AppDrawer);
```

Answer (score 7):

in new version of **reactnavigation** for open, close or toggle your `DrawerNavigator` Just use the following

```
this.props.navigation.openDrawer();
this.props.navigation.closeDrawer();
this.props.navigation.toggleDrawer();
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-based-navigation.html

Comment: Then how do i pass parameter while using `openDrawer`?

Comment: This should be marked as the Accepted Answer. Thanks!!